# How to compute average Cost in SQL based on category?

Tags: sql, database

So let's say we have a table called phone.

[image]

[image]

and i need another column to show the average cost of a brand phone
I know i can do something like this:
SELECT brand, AVG (cost)
FROM Phone
GROUP BY brand;

and get something like this table:

[image]

Can someone help me how i would get this result below using a select sql statement?

[image]

Comment:  Please consider not posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, copying and pasting text from an image is somewhat tricky.

Comment: Sorry about that. Will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use avg(cost) over (partition) such as this:

```
select *, 
 round(avg(cost) over (partition by brand), 2) as avg_cost
from phone;
```

| phoneid | brand | cost | avg_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | apple | 8 | 10.00 |
| 6 | apple | 12 | 10.00 |
| 3 | google | 7 | 6.50 |
| 4 | google | 6 | 6.50 |
| 1 | samsung | 10 | 9.33 |
| 5 | samsung | 4 | 9.33 |
| 7 | samsung | 14 | 9.33 |

---